# SceneKit + Collada + animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, blender, scenekit, collada

I am trying to use Apple's SceneKit in order to load a model from Blender in Collada (dae) format, then apply animation on it from another Collada file, just like Apple did in their Banana example. I can do this with their models and animation files, however, if I open their animation files, change something, then export them again from Blender, the animation files are corrupted and SceneKit cannot use them.

How do you create these files for your SceneKit games? What software are you using? I've tried Blender and 3dsmax, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3DSMax + OpenCollada exporter works great.

Comment: I have an issue with creating dae files containing only the animation for the skeleton - I built it in blender, then imported it into 3dsmax and exported only the animation. The animation dae file is read in SceneKit, it appears in code as a CAAnimationGroup, but it doesn't animate. Could you give me any pointers to solving this issue?

Comment: I use Cheetah3D and got my animations working but there is a bug – after applying animation the model on the scene changes it's position to (0,0,0)